# How will going from 75% Credit Utilization to 0% Credit Utilization affect my credit score?

Tags: credit-score

I currently have a 75% credit utilization, which I know is not favorable on about 35,000 revolving credit.  I am getting my year end bonus and plan on using that to completely pay off all of my credit cards leaving me with a 0% credit utilization.  Currently my credit score is 668, mostly due to my utilization, I pay everything on time, but just have too much debt, which is why i'm paying it all off.  My question is how much will paying off all my revolving credit and having a 0% utilization on 35,000 credit availability positively effect my credit score?

Comment: Maybe you should be targeting 100% utilization.  The US government is always at 100% credit utilization (according to the debt ceiling) and it has a triple A credit rating.

Comment: @Muro I don't think any government is a good model for the average person.

Comment: @Matthew - agreed.  Is it a good model for non-average people? :)

Comment: @Muro Possibly billionaire oil barons ...

Comment: @Muro it is a good model if you can take money from someone else by taxing him. For private persons it's called "robbery" though, so I wouldn't recommend it as a model - ROI on prison terms are usually low.

Comment: Bad comparison, @Muro.  The average person gets credit they might need, and then decide whether or not to spend it.  Governments decide what they *must* spend, and then worry about getting credit for it.  If the Gov were at 75% debt utilization, we would lower the debt ceiling and they would be back at 100%.

Comment: congrats on a year-end "bonus" that can pay-off ~$25k in credit card debt!

Comment: I'd much rather have a credit score of 0 and owe nothing to anyone than a perfect credit score and live in debt. Why does the probably tiny impact on your score matter to you?

Comment: @GlenPierce I know this is an old comment now, but having 0 credit means that you can't obtain a loan if you decide you need/want to in the future, which can often be a very good financial decision. That could mean a mortgage (many of which are then significantly cheaper than renting, especially in the long run), or a business loan to start your own business (often a bad investment, but one that many entrepreneurs find worthwhile), or even just a personal loan when you run into a catastrophic event that you can't pay out of pocket right away

Answer (score 29):

I wrote [an article about FICO scoring](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/your-fico-score/) which shows that 30% of your score is based on utilization or amount owed. I can't say exactly how much your score will rise, or how long it will take, but your score will improve dramatically from what you propose.

[image: Utilization Chart]

This chart is from Credit Karma, and it shows how zero utilization is actually bad when it comes to your score. I wrote an article on my blog titled [Too Little Debt](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/too-little-debt/) in which I discuss further.
Under 20% is ideal, just not zero.

Comment: Pretty good article, too

Comment: Nice answer, nice article, Joe.  Upvote from me!

Answer (score 8):

You really don't know how credit scoring works.

Let's think about the purpose of a credit score: to assess whether you're a high default risk. A lender wants to know, in this order:

1. Do you pay your debts? If so, do you pay late?
2. How long your behavior be measured?
3. Are you solvent?

Utilization factors into the solvency assessment. If you are at 100% utilization of your unsecured credit, you're insolvent -- you can't pay your bills. If you are at 0%, you're as solvent as you can be. Most people who use credit cards are somewhere in the middle.

When a bank underwrites a large loan like a mortgage or car loan, they use your credit score an application information like income and employment history to figure out what kind of loan you qualify for.

Credit cards are called "revolving" accounts for a reason -- you're supposed to use them to buy crap and pay your bill in full at the end of the month.

My advice to you:

- Identify the person who told you that you need to carry credit card debt to have good credit and **never, ever** listen to them about business matters ever again.
- Pay off all of your cards.
- Use your credit cards as you see fit, as long as you can pay them off in 30 days without paying interest.

Comment: +1 but how about identify the person who told them to carry a balance and educated them back in kindness and spread the good word?

Comment: "If you are at 100% utilization you are insolvent". Maybe I don't understand the terms but that seems wrong. If I am rich and have a very low credit limit, which I use all of, I'm not insolvent. Likewise if I use 50% of a large line of credit and then lost my job I may be insolvent.

Comment: I never gave much thought to this, till a couple years back. I had cut back on cards, and used one every month with low limit. Paid in full every month, but utilization was still high. So I requested a line increase well above what I'd use. Problem fixed.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Credit score models don't include your assets and aren't all-seeing and all-knowing. High credit scores lower default risk, but don't eliminate them. That's why smart banks underwrite loans for big loans like mortgages.

Comment: Good point, DuffBeer.  While the credit bureaus have quite a bit of data on you, they don't have *everything*, thus your report only represents a slice of the overall picture.  It's enough to help creditors understand how you've used the credit you have thus far, but that's about it.