# How does Paying credit card in full VS paying with interest will affect your credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, interest-rate, interest

What is the effect of paying credit card in full or with interest on your credit score?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Credit card issuers do not report whether you paid the balance in full to the credit reporting agencies. What is reported each month is your balance and whether you made the required payment, but not the *size* of the payment. From what I can tell, this is reported to the credit reporting agencies at about the same time as your monthly bill is issued, i.e., it's your statement balance.

If your monthly balance is reported as $4500 one month and then $4000 the next, there is no way to tell *from your credit report* whether you paid the $4500 in full and ran up another $4000 the next month, or made a single $500-ish payment and are carrying the balance.

Since this information is not on your credit report, it cannot (and does not) affect your credit score.

If the balance is *higher* than it otherwise would be because you are carrying multiple months of spending on the card rather than paying it off each month, this *can* affect your credit score because it increases utilization. The less utilization, the higher the score. It used to be that utilization didn't have *too* significant of an impact on your score until it reached 50%, but apparently it has *some* effect at 20%.

Comment: see my award winning http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/how-will-going-from-75-credit-utilization-to-0-credit-utilization-affect-my-cr/5638#5638 1-20% utilization is the sweet spot. I was ready to +1 you until you said 50%.

Comment: Yeah, good point, updated a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My plan is not to pay interest (i.e pay in full the amount every month). But some people told me not paying an interest will lower my score. I hope that might be false assumption. How about if you pay earlier than the due date. Does it also have an effect on your credit score?

Comment: Usually, no, paying early will not have an effect because it's the statement balance getting reported.

Comment: One more question to add: Does it also matter using your full credit limit (100%) or using 50% of your limit or not even using it  at all? How does that affects your credit score. Is utilization related to this? Thank you

Comment: Yes, utilization is the percentage of your available credit you're using. They measure it in total for all your accounts, but it's also calculated for each individual account.

Comment: Okay. I red one of the articles I found (http://littleadvisor.com/blog/archives/91) and didn't get what he mean by "Keep your statement balance below ~30% of your credit limit." ... If I have $1000 limit, what does the above statement mean?

Comment: For the maximum credit score, your balance should be below 30% of your limit, or $300. Keep in mind, though, that most people don't have the highest credit scores they could have, because they do use their credit.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you carry balance by itself will not affect as it is not reported.

What's reported is your current balance, whether you pay "as agreed" (i.e.: at least the minimum), and whether you pay "more than minimum" (some creditors report that as well).

However, spending more than what you can pay over prolonged periods of time will definitely lead to higher debt to credit ratio, and this is what is affecting the credit score.