# Does maintaining a low (versus zero) balance on a credit card improve your credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How will going from 75% Credit Utilization to 0% Credit Utilization affect my credit score?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/how-will-going-from-75-credit-utilization-to-0-credit-utilization-affect-my-cr)

I've read in a few places some statistics to indicate that people with zero CC balance have a lower average credit score than someone who maintains a low, yet nonzero, balance. What is the mechanism of this, if it is actually a real effect? Another possibility could be that those with zero balances don't use credit and don't have a significant credit history, leading to a lower score.

Comment: That Credit Karma graph is one of the places that I was referring to. The question is, WHY would it cause a lower credit score to have 0% CC balance, if it even occurs at all?

Comment: I answered both questions, although, I admit, the "why" is not so simple. I believe that each factor involved in creating the score was correlated to default rates, and therefore, the 0% was deemed riskier than the range of 1%-19%.

Answer (score 0):

I can't swear that it's real but one of those pseudo-credit scores you find online considered it a ding on my credit that my utilization was 0%.  They were being stupid about it, though--it's not actually 0%, just less than 1%.