# Do I have to spend money with my credit card to increase my credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I opened my first credit card a few weeks ago.

How much money do I need to spend with my credit card to increase my credit score?

Do I even need to spend money with it to increase my credit score?

Comment: Keep in mind it takes time to increase your score, even if you use it optimally it doesn't happen in a few weeks or even a few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer is use it, but use it responsibly. The point of the credit report is to prove to potential creditors that you are a responsible person who pays their bills on time. If you don't use the new credit card, you can't prove that.

However, of course there is a limit. If you max out the card, you have only proven that you are irresponsible with credit. Try to stay around 50% of your max limit. More is O.K., but **never** go over 89%.

Always pay your bills on time. *Always*. Not just this new credit card, but all bills. The best way to ruin your credit is not paying your bills. Even if you are having a dispute with a company, pay the bill anyway to save your credit and *then* dispute the situation and try to get your money back.

Prove to creditors that they can trust you and you'll have an excellent credit score.

Comment: The concepts here are great. +1.  I would quibble with the specific numbers.  @JoeTaxpayer had some very good answers regarding utilization percentages.  If I recall, he determined just under 20% to be the sweet spot.  http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/how-will-going-from-75-credit-utilization-to-0-credit-utilization-affect-my-cr/5638#5638