# Increasing score by improving utilization

Tags: credit-score

I have 3 credit cards almost maxed out at 92% utilization.

If I pay down all my credit cards to utilization totaling 20% is it possible to raise my credit score by 75 points? I am currently at 620.

Comment: Paying down your credit cards will not only increase your credit score, but save you a ton of money on interest and fees.  By all means get those paid down.  There is no need to give a lot of your paycheck to banks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How will going from 75% Credit Utilization to 0% Credit Utilization affect my credit score?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/how-will-going-from-75-credit-utilization-to-0-credit-utilization-affect-my-cr) Question is a bit different (other OP is paying to 0% utilization), but JTP's answer still applies.